# Mongodb find where count > 5

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called `caminhos` like the following document:

```js
"_id" : ObjectId("54e2aa2f71defd010b1caf5c"),
    "data" : "2015-02-17 12:40:47",
    "rua" : "Rua Caperuçu, 119–211",
    "horario" : "12:40:47",
    "localizacao" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -46.6452, 
            -23.60894
        ]
    },
    "id_usuario" : "54bef57a14b88ad70a8ab74e" }

/* 32 */ {
    "_id" : ObjectId("54e387d371defd010b1caf5d"),
    "data" : "2015-02-17 04:26:27",
    "rua" : "Rua Camaipi, 1–83",
    "horario" : "04:26:27",
    "localizacao" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -46.63184, 
            -23.47975
        ]
    },"id_usuario" : "54bef57a14b88ad70a8ab74e" }

/* 33 */ {
    "_id" : ObjectId("54e387d471defd010b1caf5e"),
    "data" : "2015-02-17 04:26:27",
    "rua" : "Rua Camaipi, 1–83",
    "horario" : "04:26:27",
    "localizacao" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -46.63179, 
            -23.47985
        ]
    },"id_usuario" : "54bef57a14b88ad70a8ab74e" }

/* 34 */ {
    "_id" : ObjectId("54e387d471defd010b1caf5f"),
    "data" : "2015-02-17 04:26:27",
    "rua" : "Rua Camaipi, 1–83",
    "horario" : "04:26:27",
    "localizacao" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -46.63177, 
            -23.47987
        ]
    },"id_usuario" : "54bef57a14b88ad70a8ab74e" }
```

I need group all documents with `id_usuario = 54bef57a14b88ad70a8ab74e` `and` same `rua` value `and` different `data` value and find/select only the groups with `count>5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a fairly basic problem which you can solve with the [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) using [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operators to get what you want.

```
db.caminhos.aggregate([
  { $match: { id_usuario: "54bef57a14b88ad70a8ab74e" } },
  { $group: { _id: { rua: "$rua", data: "$data" } } },
  { $group: { _id: "$_id.rua", data: { $push: "$_id.data" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } },
  { $match: { count: { $gt: 5 } } }
])
```

Comment: It group `ruas` by `data` and returns the `ruas` with more than 5 `data` but I need return only the results with 5 different `data` in the same `rua`

Comment: Your exact requirements are not clear in the question or really in this comment, but I think I have a guess at what you want. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: For example: I have Rua Camaipi three times on 18-02-2015, Caperucu 1 time 18-02-2015, 1 time 17-02-2015,  1 time 10-01-2015, 1 time 01-01-2015, 1 time 01-02-2014 then I want to return Caperucu without the data, only the `Rua` 's value because it has 5 different `data`

Comment: I need `data` distinct values before group and check count

Comment: please, add me in skype:igor.ladessa

Comment: The edit I made after my comment will find `rua`s with more than 5 distinct data because in the question you wrote `count > 5`. You can change the `$gt` to `$gte` if what you want a count of `5 or more`. If you don't want the `data` to come back, you should remove the `data` field in the second `$group`. I can't create chats with you because your reputation isn't high enough.

Comment: Great! it works...the data field is with timestamp...I thought that this field was only dd/mm/yyyy Thanks!